# Where TD Does Not Contain Text

Tags: jquery

I'm getting magical with some data filtering.  When hitting a drop down list I want to eliminate rows from a table where a certain column *does not* contain the text from the drop down list.  I've tried various combinations without any luck as follows:

```
$("table tr td:contains('" + $("#SupplierID :selected").text() + "')").parent().hide();
```

This obviously hides the ones that *do* contain the selected text.  I've tried not:contains but that doesn't work at all.  So yeah, I want to do the inverse of this.  And can I do it for a certain column? There's no point going through all the columns as it only applies to one column.

Cheers!

Comment: what kind of a title is this. it doesn't convey what is the actual question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(...):not(:contains(...))")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:not(:contains("text"))
```

Is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach using jQuery `not()`

- hide rows where the first (or nth) column does not contain the text "DoNotHide"

  `$('td:nth-child(1)').not($('td:contains("DoNotHide")')).parents('tr').hide()`
- or, hide all rows that do not have a column with "DoNotHide" text

  `$('tr').not($('td:contains("DoNotHide")').parents('tr')).hide();`